# Inline pipe separator between li elements in Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

Trying to add a pipe separator between links on the li:after pseudo element in Bootstrap 4 where `nav` is constructed with flex.

See image:

[image: Pipe separator between list items in Bootstrap 4]

What is the correct way to make the pipe separator inline with the links?

I do not want to add the pipe separator to `a:before` / `a:after`, it needs to remain on the `li`.

Not being overly familiar with `flex`, I am just unsure how to replicate the inline effect and I would assume using `float` would not make much sense in flex neither.

Example CSS is basically just:

```
.page-header .header.links li + li:before {
    content: " | ";
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

The Bootstrap `ul` is `display: flex` and the Bootstrap `li` are `flex: 1 1 auto`.

Comment: set `position: relative` for `li` and `position: absolute` for `li:before`

Comment: If I set the `position: absolute` on the `li:before` then I need to force set position with `left: -10px` and `top: 5px` - I was hoping for a better way using `flex`?

Comment: The more I play about with this, the more it looks like I have to set `display: flex` on the `li` element. I am unsure if that is okay to have both the `ul` and each `li` set to `display: flex`...?

Comment: Yeah, you can have `flex` on both `ul` and `li`. There is no problem with that